# Is it possible split an atomic nucleus with a resonance frequency?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, waves, atomic-physics

a).Do atomic nuclei have natural angular frequencies?
b).What would be the external force to drive the oscillator(atomic nucleus)?

Answer (score 2):

Nuclei, like molecules, have vibrational states, but the vibrational character of these states is not as pure for nuclei. You can model them as shape oscillations (usually ellipsoidal deformations about a spherical or ellipsoidal equilibrium shape), but in reality they're usually more like a slightly coherent superposition of a few different particle-hole excitations.

Some nuclei have spherical equilibrium shapes in their ground state, while others are ellipsoidal. The ellipsoidal ones can exhibit collective rotation about any principal axis that isn't a symmetry axis.

Nuclei can be excited by a variety of methods, but most of these usually do not excite any specific resonance in the sense of applying a driving force at a certain frequency. The best example I know of of what you're asking about with respect to induced fission through a vibrational resonance is that this can occur for neutron-induced fission in the actinides, and sometimes these resonances can be interpreted as vibrations that excite a state in a second superdeformed minimum of the potential.